# Unity android Error ActivityThread Failed to find provider info for com.samsung.android.app.deepsky.DeepSkyQuery.provider

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, provider

I have this error running unity 2022.3.8f1.

The game runs perfectly on windows but when I try to build and run on a mobile. It builds without any error but the app does not open in the phone. The android logcat shows this error "Error ActivityThread Failed to find provider info for com.samsung.android.app.deepsky.DeepSkyQuery.provider".

I do not find what is this provider or where I am using it in my program. I have also installed the adaptative performance for samsung android provider, but it does not solve the problem.

I do not know which information can I add to try to explain what is happening, so I hope someone knows what is going on.

Thanks in advance.

I tried to find where I am using this provider and also installing the adaptative samsung provider.